# How to delete a triggered send in SalesCloud

Tags: marketing-cloud, marketing-cloud-connect, triggered-send

We have several unused triggered send in the SalesCloud. How can we delete them?

I've already deleted the counterpart in the marketing cloud with the "move to folder and delete them"-trick, but I have no clue how I can do this in the SalesCloud.

Comment: Do you have an SFDC sandbox?

Comment: Yes, I have a sandbox. But the sandbox is not connected to the marketing cloud.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you do not have the Delete button on your layout, click on Edit Layout and drag it there.

It will be right next to the Edit button.

[image: Delete Trigger]

Answer (score 0):

You cannot modify APEX in production. It is recommended that changes are done in the Sandbox and deployed to production. This can be done using "Destructive XML". For more info please visit: https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.daas.meta/daas/daas_destructive_changes.htm

Comment: Its not an APEX class. I've added the triggered sends in the SalesCloud GUI in the tab "Marketing Cloud" and there in the section "Triggered Sends". So I don't have a class name to delete it via destructiveChanges___.xml.

Answer (score 0):

Try executing this anonymous code from your developer console

```
delete [select id from et4ae5__Automated_Send__c where id = :yourId];
```

If you want to delete all triggered sends, go with

```
delete [select id from et4ae5__Automated_Send__c];
```